# Appropriate word for a young person who behaves like a cynical old person?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives

What is an appropriate term for a young person (child or teenager) whose words and actions mimic that of a much older person from a previous generation? Such a youngster would demonstrate strong nostalgia for the past, despite never having lived during that time period.

An example I can think of is a 12 year old boy who observes that, "children nowadays spend all their time with their faces glued to smartphones", or who prefers to write letters rather than emails, "like it was done in the good old days". This child would never have a Facebook or Twitter account, because they are, "silly fads of the 21st century".<sup>1</sup>

A possible phrase would be *mature beyond his years*, although that doesn't quite capture the characteristic in question—in particular the underlying contradiction, cynicism, and nostalgia.

I can think a perfectly fitting term from another language, but not English...

<sub><sup>1</sup>The motivation behind this question is  an interesting youngster I know who makes these statements!</sub>

Comment: Scottish? (joke).  It's not **precocious**, that's different.  Really the only way I can think to describe that is "surprisingly XYZ has the outlook of an old-fogey"

Comment: I think we just call them *little adults*

Comment: @tchrist, the connotation can be either positive or negative. Most phrases will tend to be humorous, although I wonder if there is a formal term.

Comment: I have this problem a lot (not that I'm mature, but that I'm grumpy like an old man) and I just get called cynical mostly.  My friends also turned my name into a term for this.  So maybe there you go; you have to make up your own term based on someone's name.  Or just call them a George.

Comment: @jesterII *Wise beyond their years* carries positive connotation, as perhaps(?) would *a diligent student of yesteryear*, but you seem to be looking for something that would be negative, something that casts judgement on this person, whether wrapped in humorous sarcasm or is more direct. I ask because knowing which focus you are looking for will help guide answerers to making the sort of solution you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks for the help @tchrist. I suppose I am not so sure what exactly I am looking for (I have no need for an answer beyond personal interest). The creativity of the community will be a big help.

Comment: I've always used the phrase, "n going on x". For example, "My daughter is 3 going on 30."

Comment: How about "grumpy beyond his years"?

Comment: The primary characteristic of any 12-year-old who earnestly repeats the reactionary attitudes of his parents (and other much older adults) in this way is probably that he's ***easily-led, unquestioning, servile.*** Or perhaps just ***eager to please***, since unless we assume the kid is an idiot, the only reason he might think badly of the way current technology enhances communication would be ***because his Luddite parents keep harping on about "the good old days"*** (which they *weren't*, and which the kid himself knows little about anyway).

Comment: "mature" is the word you're going for.

Comment: @jesterII - what is the term from the other language?

Comment: @GeorgeCapote But if you're going to use "George" as the term to describe someone like this, you have to say it like Lennie Small.  ""I was only foolin', George."

Comment: I like beans with ketchup ^.^

Comment: The word I would use to describe this person is an Ockhamite: one who adheres to Ockham's Razor.

He rejects trappings that he perceives as superfluous, whether they are useful towards a purpose or not.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. One question asks for a word that describes a feeling, and the other question asks for a word that describes a person.

Comment: @phenry I fully agree. How could the top rated answers *wistful* and *yearning* apply to a pre-teen who prefers to ignore modern technology? A wistful child describes someone very different from the OP's description If it were true that this question is a duplicate then why is it that there are no duplicate answers?!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A young person who demonstrates wisdom and maturity beyond their years is often called an *old soul*. It comes from the belief that some reincarnated souls retain a measure of the wisdom and character developed in previous incarnations. These days, even those who don't share in the actual belief find use for the phrase in normal conversation. I'd be perfectly comfortable referring to the boy you describe with this term.

Comment: Only that the behaviour described in the question is the sign neither of maturity nor wisdom

Comment: It's true that the term typically describes advanced maturity and wisdom. However, I still feel it's the best term in this particular scenario because of its origin in the concept of reincarnation. If the original belief is taken for granted, then the term implies that the child literally experienced those things which they now express nostalgia for, providing a practical explanation for their otherwise unusual preference for the old-fashioned. This is why it was the very first thought that came to mind when I read the question.

Comment: With several strong answers to choose from, I find that "old soul" is a good description of the quality in question.

Answer (score 16):

*Sclerotic*: an inability to adapt. For example,

> That boy Tim is a sclerotic kid — age 13 going on 65.

Comment: +1 more for "13 going on 65" than sclerotic

Answer (score 14):

He sounds like a *[fuddy-duddy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fuddy-duddy)*

> one that is old-fashioned, unimaginative, or conservative [*Merriam-Webster*]

The term is not limited to children, but is often applied to someone who seems old beyond their years.

You also might consider *[fogey](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fogey)*

> an extremely fussy, old-fashioned, or conservative person (esp in the phrase old fogey) [*Collins*]

In this case, he's a *young fogey*.

You also might consider *[relic](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/relic)*

> (informal) an old or old-fashioned person or thing [*Collins*]

And finally, *[throwback](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throwback)*

> one that is suggestive of or suited to an earlier time or style: *his manners were a throwback to a more polite era* [*Merriam-Webster*]

Comment: The first three are usually applied to people who are *actually* old, not young people *acting* old. "Throwback" works in the example sentence given.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner "young fogey" implies exactly that (young person acting old) It was the first phrase that came to my mind on reading the question and scanned down to see if any of the answers already mentioned it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: "Young fogey" is not all that common around here.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I don't know where "round here" is. I've seen this in the British press.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Ah, I'm "'round here" in the colonies. ;) It's a phrase I've heard, but certainly not often.

Answer (score 13):

The lad you speak of has an *anachronistic* perspective.

*Anachronistic* may seem to be a stretch here, but when you think about it, an anachronistic perspective (attitude, outlook, way of looking at things) is a perspective that is somehow out of order chronologically.

Very often we think of anachronistic thinking as backward-looking, from the perspective of the present, such as the existence today of "colored only" drinking fountains or "colored only" restrooms, which are things of the past. Why couldn't a forward-looking perspective be anachronistic in the sense that it is ahead of its time?

Someone feel free to correct me if I'm off base.

Answer (score 10):

As I native North American English speaker, I would colloquially refer to the person you described as *old-school*. Meriam-Webster defines that term as:

> [*old-school*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old-school)
>
> - typical of an earlier style or form
> - based on a way of doing things that was common in the past
> - using or supporting traditional practices

So for example:

> Joey is old-school.  He listens to all of his music on vinyl.

You will also often hear the term *old soul*, but this usually refers more to maturity or emotional outlook than to an individual’s interests in technology or tradition.

Comment: I'd prefer *old soul* to *old school* here, in as much as *old school" has connotations of a trendy adoption of a "retro" aesthetic, where this child seems to be deliberately flouting trends.

Answer (score 9):

"Born middle-aged" is a phrase I have heard applied to such people (including myself, actually). There are plenty of matches on Google for that phrase. The OED says that "middle-aged" can be used for "*resembling* a person in middle age", so you can interpret the phrase in that sense.

Answer (score 7):

My son was like this when younger, and his Scoutmaster remarked once that he appeared to be

> working on his Running-for-the-Senate merit badge.

Answer (score 7):

*"Born too late"* is a moderately common phrase, as popularized by Edwin Arlington Robinson's poem "[Miniver Cheevy](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/174244)":

> ... Miniver loved the days of old
>       When swords were bright and steeds were prancing;
>   The vision of a warrior bold
>       Would set him dancing.
>
> [...]
>
> Miniver Cheevy, born too late,
>       Scratched his head and kept on thinking;
>   Miniver coughed, and called it fate,
>       And kept on drinking.

Comment: I would consider this term to be very applicable if one could assume a context.  If he is like this because of his own personality, then yes; if he is merely reflecting the opinions of Luddites, then I would think it does not apply.  Contextualizing his circumstances is very important for identifying the correct term in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest ***nostalgist***. It seems like there is no word that covers both being young and nostalgic, but *nostalgist* conveys the idea in the context. You can use ***nostalgic*** as an adjective also, as in *a nostalgic person*.

Nostalgist is the noun version of nostalgic but [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nostalgist) mentions that it is used among young people and includes regional slang terms:

> Someone who always believes the items, fads, morals of the past are better than what is comparable today. Someone who fanatically believes that something today can never be as good as the thing of the past.
>
> ---
>
> (noun) One who looks constantly to nostalgia to save the day.
> This word has been adopted by young culture in cities across the country. Regional slang synonyms include coconut boost and taleggio.

---

Other than that, it is mentioned as the *nostalgia of the young* in online articles along with having *retrospective* characteristic or feelings.

In psychology, there is a phenomenon called *reminiscence bump* which is the tendency for older adults to remember the past. Scientists also found a term for the nostalgia for a time that you haven't experienced that is seen among young people. It is called ***cascading reminiscence bump*** and mostly related to music, which is being nostalgic for music that was being played before you were born.

<sub>Here is the article for further read: 

http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/cusp/201309/nostalgia-time-you-didnt-know</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think [old-fashioned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Old-fashioned) can well describe the characteristics you are describing:

> - favouring or adopting the dress, manners, fashions, etc, of a former time
> - Scot and Northern English: old for one's age: an old-fashioned child.

Source:
Collins English Dictionary

Comment: I would read *old-fashioned* as a child who resembles the children of the past, rather than as a child who resembles the old people of the present.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest perhaps a *cynic*, or a *cynical 12 year old*.

> ***cynic -*** *noun.* a person who believes that people are motivated purely by self-interest rather than acting for honourable or unselfish reasons.

While the term cynic in itself doesn't capture 'young person who acts like a jaded old person', in context both mentioning that they're *young* and that they're *cynical* gives the impression that they act old and jaded.

Perhaps also *jaded* would be appropriate.

> ***jaded*** - *adj.* bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite curious to learn that if a 12-year-old child shuns Facebook, Twitter, computer games, and is not glued 24/7  to their smart phone then he or she could be classed as being *old*, *cynical*, *fuddy-duddy*, *fogey*, quaintly *old-fashioned* or manipulated by antiquarian-minded parents.

I disagree with the above analysis so may I suggest the following, less biased, phrases:

- He is (at heart) *a 20th century boy*
- An *out of sync/synch* youngster
- An [unconventional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconventional) teenager
- An old person trapped in a young body.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment that rejection of those particular services should not immediately garner disdainful or dismissive connotations; however, the world of communications is changed drastically over the last 10 years.  When "most" people make a phone call "nowadays" that is not immediately answered, the assumption is that they are being ignored.  They assume they are calling someone's pocket. It happens to me all the time when I have my ringer off for privacy or phone off all together to conserve battery.  The word I would use to describe this situation is an "Ockham."

Comment: or "Ockhamite"/"Ockhamist" : One who adheres to and follows Ockham's Razor.

Comment: Note also that if you are a 12 year old wishing to go into Marketing, Sales, Advertisement, or any myriad of other fields that require communication with people in the modern world, completely dismissing services such as Facebook, Twitter, etc could set you very far behind the 8 ball.  If you are a 12 year old seeking a career in software development, avoiding computer games and smartphones all together would do the same....context.

Comment: @K.AlanBates there are many other careers a twelve-year old boy could be interested in, besides I don't think not having an account with Facebook or twitter, or liking video games will necessarily preclude a future in marketing etc. I quite like the idea of a pre-teen who's into writing letters with a pen and listening to vinyl records, the real dilemma is whether his peers will respect his lifestyle or will he be teased and ridiculed?

Comment: If you haven't figured out what you want to do by the time you're 12, you'll be late to the game (that's a joke)  ...I was merely mentioning valid cases where those services and tasks are not superfluous to one's aims.  The mentioning of specific services like Facebook and twitter misses the mark, if eve so slightly. Sure, not using one of those services does no particular harm, but taking an Amish approach to modern technology will put you out of place in the job market; unless you live in Des Moines. They're at least 10 years behind current standards.

Comment: I still hold that the best word to describe someone who "ignores superfluous things and does not participate in fads" is "Okhamite."

It is perfectly neutral, to my eyes.  It doesn't carry the negative connotations of "cynical" or "curmudgeon" but it also does not carry the seemingly positive connotations of "nostalgic" or "old soul."  An Ockhamite may be making a mistake by ignoring necessary complexity; they may be improving themselves by simplifying their lives. It's neutral.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, I would call such a person an *old fogey*.

Comment: No we wouldn't, because he isn't, he's 12. One might however say he is "*behaving like* an old fogey", but that's not really what OP wants (or would presumably be happy with "behaving like an old cynical person")

Comment: How about a _young fogey_?

Comment: This suggestion is discussed in more detail in @bib's answer.

Answer (score 0):

### A Young Curmudgeon

The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curmudgeon) defines curmudgeon thusly:

> *noun*
>
> A bad-tempered or surly person.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curmudgeon) says:

> An ill-tempered (and frequently old) person full of stubborn ideas or opinions.

If the person is young, they may be [called out as a young curmudgeon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gwyG_Qd9h_EC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=young%20curmudgeon&source=bl&ots=9P5zjz1DOG&sig=d2vbz_yLzEAhfpGDuwHotFzNZ24&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBThQahUKEwiG75_YtuzGAhWBCNsKHTPgCuE#v=onepage&q=young%20curmudgeon&f=false).

> Sixty year old Victor Meldrew has not taken kindly to impending senior citizenship. While he seems destined to live out his life as an old curmudgeon, we get the impression that he was a young curmudgeon as well.

Answer (score -1):

curmudgeon - a crusty,  ill-tempered, and usually old man

Answer (score -2):

I like @dwjohnston's suggested ***jaded***. Given that the suffix ***-ette*** often means "small, young" (c.f. French *cadette = younger sister*, BrE *ladette = loutish young woman*), I propose the neologism...

> ***jadette*** *- [prematurely] jaded young person*

Since it's not yet in the dictionary, I don't know whether it's pronounced with a long or a short 'a'.

Comment: Maybe, but to me, *jaded* is mainly about having lost pleasure in things that others enjoy, having experienced them to the point of boredom; whereas the described boy seems to dislike modern things for other reasons than having tried them a lot and become disillusioned. 'Jaded' also seems wholly negative, whereas this boy likes the things of yesteryear.

Comment: @LarsH: Honestly, how is one to speculate on how this poor kid came by his unusual attitudes? OP knows him, but we don't. All we can say for sure is that he's at the very least *atypical*, and I'd be quite prepared to go so far as *abnormal*. But I wouldn't have a problem accusing someone of having a "jaded" outlook if they affected boredom with some activity I happen to know they actually have little or no personal experience of. The word reflects a current attitude, not the past history leading up to that attitude.

Comment: I was going by the OP's statement, that the boy "would never have a Facebook or Twitter account," and therefore is inexperienced in such things. M-W's definitions of *jaded* include "by having done or experienced too much of something" and "by experience or by surfeit."

Comment: @LarsH: You're repeating yourself. Like I said, dictionary definitions notwithstanding, I'm happy to describe someone as "jaded" simply because he says something is boring, even if he personally has never done it, and therefore never been "bored" by it.

Comment: I don't see the repetition. I was appealing to more objective sources than our speculations about what the boy has done, and our differing personal feelings about what "jaded" means.

Answer (score -4):

I would call him an oxymoron. In the very nature of the word that is what you have here.

Comment: You'd call him [a figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oxymoron)? I don't think that's the right answer.

Answer (score -5):

Pessimist, depressed, or just brain-washed by an elder.