# A fitting word/description for a person who seems more mature in appearance than most people his age?

Tags: phrases

I'm trying to describe a person who is young (in his youth 19-24, past teenage years) who at a first glance might look mature or wiser for his age. But if you talk to him you get to know him as a little naive though only in experience but not in wisdom.

So I have a description like "His face is calm and impassive and combined with his white hair makes him look wiser than 19"

- Can I use a word or phrase that can define this kind of person without giving away details?
- And is the description even correct to explain this kind of person?

Comment: There is an expression, 'wise beyond his years' but it usually relates to someone's behaviour, not to their appearance. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beyond+his+years%2Cbeyond+her+years&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeyond%20his%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeyond%20her%20years%3B%2Cc0

Comment: How many people aged 19 to 24 have white hair? And what would it indicate if they did - other than that they are genetically predisposed to have white hair at a young age?

Comment: @WS2 I had two girl friends whose hair were turning grey in their twenties. And like it or not, they looked older because of it. Grey is often associated with the passage of time.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Presumably it works different in Italian, but in English that would be *two people whose hair **was** turning grey*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have heard the term *grey beard* used to describe a mature man. Now that I literally fit that description, I am no clearer as to whether I am any the wiser.

Comment: @FumbleFingers a slip up, too many years in Italy the two languages get muddled. Happens.

Comment: Related: [young person who behaves like a cynical old person?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187467/appropriate-word-for-a-young-person-who-behaves-like-a-cynical-old-person?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Older than his years** may fit, applying both for appearence and mind.

> [Example 1](http://www.evoke.ie/showbiz/but-hes-only-38-colin-farrell-looks-older-than-his-years-as-he-shows-off-scruffy-beard-on-way-to-yoga-class-in-santa-monica): *But he’s only 38! Colin Farrell looks older than his years as he shows
>   off scruffy beard on way to yoga class in Santa Monica*.
>
> Example 2: *All this profuse, indiscriminate reading helped to educate him and to give him the air of a "wise child," older than his years and familiar
>   with the ways of the world*.

Answer (score 6):

The term **precocious** is applied to a person who develops skills or characteristics much earlier than usual.

Comment: ...but is usually only applied to children.  Certainly I would not use it in the context of a 19-24 year-old young adult.

Comment: I'm wondering...Is there something that a 19-24 year old adult might be skilled at that most adults generally achieve, if at all, only years later?  If so, wouldn't you refer to that young adult as precocious?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, one will hear the term "old soul" for someone who seems to demonstrate wisdom that beyond their years.

Answer (score 4):

If the person has white hair, they might be termed ["venerable"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerable), or even better (rubbing in any disparity between their  looks and their acts) "**venerable-looking**". Like, for example, in the title of [this dissertation](http://uir.unisa.ac.za/handle/10500/4774).

Answer (score 2):

I think *an old head on young shoulders* fits the person you describe quite well.

Answer (score 1):

His **reserved demeanor** makes him seem more mature than his peers.

(Some youngen with white hair isn't going to fool me, unless they also know when to keep their mouth shut.)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term **worldly** used in this context.

Answer (score 1):

His visage denotes wisdom-experience-years-maturity beyond his age.
Of course, transposing the words age and years is an option...

age beyond his years  or  years beyond his age.